# Structure of importable pytest plugin

Tags: python, pytest, directory-structure

I have some data/fixtures that are common across several projects. So the sensible thing to do is to refactor them into a standalone project and import them in the projects. Structure of the project I'm about to refactor looks like this:

```
my-project/
    src/
        db/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
    tests/
        data/
            test_data.csv
        test_module1.py
```

`test_module1.py` contains both the fixtures to be refactored and the unit tests for `module1.py`. The official way to share fixtures is via [pytest-plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html). The official documentation provides the following `pyproject.toml` example:

```
# sample ./pyproject.toml file
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "myproject"
classifiers = [
    "Framework :: Pytest",
]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["myproject"]

[project.entry_points]
pytest11 = [
    "myproject = myproject.pluginmodule",
]
```

My questions are:

1. Do I refactor the fixtures and data from `tests/` into `new-fixture-project/src/test_data/` (like a regular package)? Or `new-fixture-project/tests/`?
2. In either case, what should the entry point be? Is it `new-fixture-project = test_data.data` (suppose I've refactored the fixtures into `test_data/data.py`?

[Edit]
Answer to my question in the comment, this is what you need to build it as a regular package.

In `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

In `setup.cfg`, add this section

```
[options.entry_points]
pytest11 =
    test_data = test_data.plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an open-source python project you can look into for reference: [pytest-mock-generator](https://github.com/pksol/pytest-mock-generator).

Instead of `src` directory, the project is structured like so:

```
new-fixture-project/
    new_fixture_project/
        db/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
    tests/
        data/
            test_data.csv
        test_module1.py
```

So to your questions - the fixtures and code go to `new-fixture-project/new_fixture_project/`.

The entry point is `new_fixture_project`, which is the module name (instead of src), if you define your fixtures in the root `__init__.py` for simplicity. You can also define your fixtures in `module1.py` for example, then the entry point would be `new_fixture_project.module1`.

Few useful links from my project:

- [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/pksol/pytest-mock-generator/blob/master/pyproject.toml)
- [**init**.py](https://github.com/pksol/pytest-mock-generator/blob/master/pytest_mock_generator/__init__.py)

Comment: Sorry more on this. As `pyproject.toml` now uses `hatchling` rather than `setuptools`, I can't build/install it by `pip install -e .`. How do you build this into a pip project (preferably editable)?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Did not encounter this use case.

Comment: Added solution to my original question. Thanks again